# How do Jews view the word "han·nā·ḥāš" in Genesis 3:1?

Tags: parashat-bereishit

> Genesis 3:1
>  a. Now **THE serpent was** the most cunning of all the wild animals that the LORD God had made
>   b. **He** said to the woman, "Did God really say, 'You can't eat from any tree in the garden?'"

From the English translation above, my English understanding are :
1. the word "serpent" is not an animal kind which we know today ---> snake
2. the definite article "the" from "*the serpent*" is telling something which the reader/listener already know to "what/whom" is the writer referring to.
3. the "was" from "*the serpent was*" show that it's a definite singular.
4. The writer is not telling a science knowledge that there is ONE MALE serpent which is the most cunning of all the wild animals, even from within other serpents kind animal. 
In other words, the writer didn't mean to tell that (as the writer know that his readers/listeners already know) there are Cobra, Python, Water snake, Rice field snake, etc. These kind of snakes are all cunning and can talk, but one male snake from (for example) the Cobra kind is the most cunning of all those snakes kind and other animal kind).

Since my English is limited, I'm not so sure if my understanding is correct or not. Anyway, since I don't know at all about Hebrew language, that's why I ask the question as in my title: How do Jews view the word "han·nā·ḥāš" in Genesis 3:1?

Comment: Thank you for the editing, msh210